# Unable to Invoke SMS on Blackberry Z10

Tags: c++, blackberry, sms, qml, invocation

I'm trying to invoke SMS from blackberry through QML on button click action but its showing error. This is my code.

```
    Button {
              id:smsTrigger
              onClicked: {
                  smsSendInvocation.query.updateQuery();
                  smsSendInvocation.trigger(smsSendInvocation.query.invokeActionId);
              }
          }

 attachedObjects: [

  Invocation {
                id: smsSendInvocation
                query.mimeType: "application/text_messaging"
                query.invokeTargetId: "sys.pim.text_messaging.smsuri"
                query.invokeActionId: "bb.action.COMPOSE"
                query.data: "body::Hello world!
                to:json:[\"2125551212\",\"9785551234\"]"

            }]
```

This is the error that it shows

```
InvocationWrapper::onQueryFinished: no matching result from Menu Service for query
   mimeType="application/text_messaging"
   uri=QUrl("") 
   data= "body::Hello world!
                to:json:["2125551212","9785551234"]" 
   metadata= QMap() 
   perimeter= 0 
   action= "bb.action.COMPOSE" 
   target= "sys.pim.text_messaging.smsuri" 
   invokerIncluded= false 
InvocationPrivate::onQueryResolved: no result matching query, no armed signal sent
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks